# Suggestions for rapid cloud app development

Tags: web-apps, web-development, cloud-service

I'm looking for a recommendation for technology / software to build rapidly apps with cloud storage, mostly with time series data.

The basic structure can be broke down into three pieces:

- Responsive front-end
- Framework
- Big data time series database

Comment: As we don't recommend "technology", we need a few more facts to be able to recommend software: What OS should it run on? What is your price limit when it comes to paid solution? What programming language(s) are to be supported (must/preferred)?

Comment: This project is in design phase, thus in this point there is not restrictions about OS, propietary / open source or programming languages. I aim to get some starting points, not final and concrete solutions. That's why I ask for technology and suggestions. I would like to have some ideas to nail down a good working solution and take a decision.

Comment: Sorry, but that makes it quite broad. This site is about final and concrete solutions, not general conceptions. You might have good reasons asking for "technologies" – but this is not what this site is dealing with.

Comment: Your questions is very broad. You can look into something like Warewolf -
 https://warewolf.io 
Rapid line of business applications, is open source, has free trial, runs on Windows. You can also get it on an Azure VM or AWS machine image for cloud integration.